# How can I get an answer for a problem described in an old, closed question?

Tags: support, bounty, closed-questions

I'm having trouble finding the process or procedure for handling a question that was closed but needs a bounty to improve answers. The question is [During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16416866/) and it was closed as *"not a real question"*. I'm experiencing the same problem on AIX under GDB.

I'm not sure what the procedure is for handling things. I want to place a bounty on the question to improve answers and gather more information, but I can't because it is closed. If I ask the same question, then the question I ask should be closed as a duplicate. A new question should also be closed as *"not a real question"*, too.

I find lots of hits for closing questions with bounties, but I'm having trouble finding information on a bounty for a closed question.

What is the procedure to follow in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The close reason is an old one; in this case it largely corresponds to "Unclear what you're asking", since the asker doesn't provide enough details to do more than guess at an answer.

You should probably post a new question, with details specific to your situation, and - if it remains unanswered - bounty *that*.

Comment: Thanks Shog. *"... since the asker doesn't provide enough details to do more than guess at an answer"* - unfortunately, the message GDB provides is *`During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed`*. GDB works great in IA-32 Linux. It pretty much sucks on other processors and platforms, like AIX, OS X, Solaris, MIPS, ARM64, PPC (or at least that's been my cross-platform experience with it).

Answer (score 3):

You're not finding any information because **it can't be done**. Bounties and closure are mutually exclusive. You can't close a question with a bounty, and you can't post a bounty on a closed question.

The question has to be reopened first. Then you can add a bounty as usual.